# How to prove independence in the following case?

Tags: random-variable, independence

Let $f$ be a (possibly randomized) function with finite domain $D$ and finite range $R$, such that for any two $x$ and $x'$ in the domain, $f(x)$ and $f(x')$ are identically distributed; i.e.:
$$\forall x,x'\in D, \forall y\in R \quad \Pr[f(x)=y] = \Pr[f(x')=y] \enspace. \qquad (\dagger)$$

I want to prove that the output of $f$ is independent of any input distribution. That is, for any discrete input distribution $X$ with [support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_%28mathematics%29) $D$, we have:
$$\forall x\in D, \forall y\in R \quad \Pr[f(x)=y \mid X=x]=\Pr[f(x)=y] \enspace. \qquad (\ddagger)$$

---

Here's two examples that satisfy $(\dagger)$, and therefore satisfy $(\ddagger)$:

**Example 1.** $f(x)$ is a constant function.

**Example 2.** Domain $D$ is the set of $n$-bit strings, and $f(x)=x \oplus r$. That is, $f$ picks a random $n$-bit string (internally), and XORs it to its input.

Comment: Isn't this result immediate, given that the output of $f$ is a weighted average (i.e., a *mixture*) of identical distributions?

Comment: @whuber: I think it must be quite intuitive, but I was unable to prove it. Could you please expand your comment into an answer? Specifically, the term *mixture* was new to me. I looked it up in Wikipedia and understood the concept, but it's not immediate for me how $f$ is a mixture of identical distributions, and how this proves the theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Definitions and clarification

Let $f$ be a randomized function from $D$ to $R$.  In the context of the question this implies that for each $x\in D$, $f$ assigns a probability $f(x,y)$ to each $y\in R$. (Actually, it does not matter that $f(x,y)$ is a probability: it merely has to be any element of a real vector space, such as a real number or tuple of real numbers.  Probabilities are real numbers.)

Suppose $p$ is a probability distribution over $D$ (entailing, in particular, that $\sum_{x\in D}p(x)=1$; it turns out this is all we need to know about $p$).  Then--this is how I interpret the question--$p$ acts on $f$ by *mixing* it to create a probability distribution $f^{(p)}$ on $R$ where, for any $y\in R$,

$$f^{(p)}(y) = \sum_{x\in D} p(x) f(x,y).$$

(When all the $f(x,*)$ are probability distributions and $p$ is itself a probability distribution, then in fact $f^{(p)}$ is itself a probability distribution: this is straightforward to show.  But that doesn't matter for this demonstration.)

#### Solution

Suppose $f(x,y)$ is independent of $x$ (which is the assumption of the question); that is, we may write $f(x,y) = g(y)$ for some function $g$.  Then

$$f^{(p)}(y)  = \sum_{x\in D} p(x) f(x,y) = \sum_{x\in D} p(x) g(y) =  g(y)\sum_{x\in D}p(x) = g(y)1 = g(y),$$

*QED*.

Comment: Nice! Just one point: consider my example 2, which with your notation is defined as $f(x,y)=x\oplus y$. We cannot find any function $g$ such that $f(x,y)=g(y)$.

Comment: Sure you can, but first you have to be consistent about how you think of $f$. $f(x,y)$ is a *number*, not a string: it gives the probability $\Pr(x\oplus r=y)$. This is a constant value of $f(x,y) = 2^{-n} = g(y)$ for each $y\in R$. For a concrete example, let $D=R=\{00,01,10,11\}$ (the case $n=2$). Consider $x=10$: with equal probability $r=00, 01, 10,$ and $11,$ whence with equal probability $x\oplus r$ is equal to $10, 11, 00,$ and $01$, respectively. *Ergo,* $f(10,10)=f(10,11)=f(10,00)=f(10,01)=1/4$. The same result holds for all other $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I will compact notation a bit. We have a discrete support, $D=\{x_1,...,x_n\}$. We define the events $f_i:\{f(x_i)=y\}, \; f_k:\{f(x_k)=y\},\; i,k =1,...,n$
Then, for any given $y$, your premise can be written as  $$\Pr(f_i) = \Pr(f_k)\; \forall i,k$$
and you want to show that 
$$\Pr(f_i|x_i) = \Pr(f_i)\; \forall i$$
By Bayes theorem
$$\Pr(f_i) = \sum_i^n\Pr(f_i|x_i)\Pr(x_i) $$ $$= \Pr(f_i|x_1)\Pr(x_1)+...+\Pr(f_i|x_i)\Pr(x_i)+...+\Pr(f_i|x_n)\Pr(x_n)$$
But $\Pr(f_i|x_k) = 0 \;\;\forall\, k\neq i$. If the realized value of $X$ is $x_k\;, k\neq i$, the event ${f(x_i)=y}$ is impossible, because $f(x_i)$ is impossible - only $f(x_k)$ is possible  . So we are left with

$$\Pr(f_i) =  \Pr(f_i|x_i)\Pr(x_i)$$.

So what we wanted to prove is not correct. But it seemed fairly intuitive... There is another relation here that I believe represents this intuition. Use a prime to denote that all previous analysis is conducted for the probability that $f$ takes the value $y'$. Then we will arrive at 
$$\Pr(f'_i) =  \Pr(f'_i|x_i)\Pr(x_i)$$

Combining the two results we obtain

$$\frac {\Pr(f_i)}{\Pr(f_i|x_i)} = \frac {\Pr(f'_i)}{\Pr(f'_i|x_i)} $$

$$\Rightarrow \frac {\Pr(f_i)}{\Pr(f'_i)} = \frac {\Pr(f_i|x_i)}{\Pr(f'_i|x_i)} $$

Moreover, since $\Pr(f_i)=\Pr(f_k)$ and $\Pr(f'_i)=\Pr(f'_k)$ we obtain

$$ \frac {\Pr(f_i)}{\Pr(f'_i)} = \frac {\Pr(f_i|x_i)}{\Pr(f'_i|x_i)} =\frac {\Pr(f_k|x_k)}{\Pr(f'_k|x_k)}=\frac {\Pr(f_k)}{\Pr(f'_k)}$$

The key here is that the realization of some $x_i$ may affect the distribution of $f(x)$ -but it will do it in a way that leaves *relative* probabilities unchanged.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer. But I think the statement $\Pr(f_i|x_k) = 0 \;\;\forall\, k\neq i$ is not correct. For instance, if $f$ is the zero function, then $\Pr(f(x_i)=0|x_k)=1$.

Comment: I didn't treat the "f is a constant" case" -it is not interesting. The interest arises when the value of $f$ actually depends on $x$

Comment: Fair enough, but for me, $f(x)=x \oplus r$ is an "interesting" case (see Example 2 in question). Then, for any $y \in R$, we have $\Pr(f(x_i)=y|x_k)=\frac{1}{|R|} \ne 0$. So, I think it's rather hard (or even impossible) to find even trivial examples with $\Pr(f(x_i)=0|x_k)=1$.

Comment: My conceptual problem here, is that the realization of some $x_i$ makes the concurrent realization of any other $x_k$ impossible -and so it makes also impossible any event depending on these other $x_k$'s.

Comment: I understand $\Pr(f(x_i)=y|x_k)$ as $\Pr(f(x_i)=y|X=x_k)$, which means the probability that the outcome of (the possibly randomized function) $f(x_i)$ is $y$, given that the outcome of $X$ is $x_k$. It does not mean that the outcome of $X$ is simultaneously both $x_i$ and $x_k$.

Comment: Me too. But since $X=x_k$ and we condition on that, it means that $f$ takes as input the specific $x_k$, not any other $x$. in that case, isn't it true that $ \Pr(f(x_i\neq x_k) = y |X=x_k)$ is zero?